# Flutter make only one third of a Container tappable

Tags: flutter

I wanted to make a Card tile that is tappable only on the right 1/3rd of the card. Because of that I cannot wrap the entire card with the GestureDetector widget so I tried to wrap the text inside the Flex widget instead. Unfortunately that means only the small text widget is tappable ignoring the all of the Container padding. What's the best approach to fix it?

I know it's possible to wrap the text widget with a margin and remove the padding but I wan't to avoid that so that I don't have to define the margin for both left and right text widgets.

Image to better illustrate the issue:

[image]

Example widget to replicate the problem:

```
return Card(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2),
      elevation: 0,
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 8,
          vertical: 60,
        ),
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Row(children: [
          Flexible(
            flex: 2,
            fit: FlexFit.tight,
            child: Text("foooo"),
          ),
          Flexible(
            flex: 1,
            fit: FlexFit.tight,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: someFunction,
              child: Text(
                "baaar",
                textAlign: TextAlign.right,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` to the `Row`, and wrap the children of `Flexible` with `Center`, like so:

```
Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
  children: [
    Flexible(
      flex: 2,
      fit: FlexFit.tight,
      child: Center(
        child: Text("foooo"),
      ),
    ),
    Flexible(
      flex: 1,
      fit: FlexFit.tight,
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {},
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            "baaar",
            textAlign: TextAlign.right,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

***Edit:***
If you want the child to determine the height, you can do:

```
Row(
  children: [
    Flexible(
      flex: 2,
      fit: FlexFit.tight,
      child: Text("foooo"),
    ),
    Flexible(
      flex: 1,
      fit: FlexFit.tight,
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {},
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Text(
            "baaar",
            textAlign: TextAlign.right,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

And remove the padding from the container (or better, remove the container you don't need it).

Comment: This sort of works but requires me to impose a height that the widget expands to. I'd rather still have it the size of the text plus some padding.